# Django count() function

Tags: python, django

(noob question I know) Hi everybody, I keep having a problem with the count() function. 
In my website I added some items to the database, then I'd like to show on the hompage the number of items, but the count doesn't show up. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

this is the code:
View.py:

```
class homeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search/home.html'

    def conto(self):
        album = Info.objects.all().count()
        return album
```

Html file:

```
<h3 style="text-align:center;"> ALBUM TOTALI: {{album}} </h3>
```

Comment: If you want to display custom variables in the template, I believe you have to supply a `get_context_data()` method.

Comment: I did what @johnGordon said, and obiovsly it worked aahah sorry I'm really new to Django

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the `get_context_data` method of the `TemplateView` you are inheriting from:

```
class homeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['album'] = Info.objects.all().count()
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render this with:

```
<h3 style="text-align:center;"> ALBUM TOTALI: {{ view.conto }} </h3>
```

This works because the [**`ContextMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin) passes the view to the template under the name `view`, and you can thus access the method with `view.conto`.

Comment: Ah that's great! I'll keep it in mind because could be very useful for other things. Thanks a lot!